# MySQL combine multiple SELECT and JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have two queries:

```
SELECT `u`.*, `ic`.*  FROM `users` `u`,
  JOIN `invitation_codes` `ic`
    ON `ic`.user_id = `u`.id
 WHERE `u`.`mail` = :mail AND `is_deleted` = 0;
```

AND

```
SELECT *  FROM `users`,
  (SELECT `level`  FROM `point_thresholds` WHERE :points BETWEEN `low_threshold` AND `top_threshold`) AS level,
  (SELECT `level_name` FROM `point_thresholds` WHERE :points BETWEEN `low_threshold` AND `top_threshold`) AS level_name
  WHERE `mail` = :mail AND `is_deleted` = 0;
```

Now I am trying to combine this queries into one:

```
SELECT `u`.*, `ic`.*  FROM `users` `u`,
  (SELECT `level`  FROM `point_thresholds` WHERE :points BETWEEN `low_threshold` AND `top_threshold`) AS level,
  (SELECT `level_name` FROM `point_thresholds` WHERE :points BETWEEN `low_threshold` AND `top_threshold`) AS level_name
  JOIN `invitation_codes` `ic`
  ON `ic`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
  WHERE `u`.`mail` = :mail AND `is_deleted` = 0;
```

Unfortunately he gets the error **#1054 - Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'** and I have no idea why, theoretically everything looks quite OK. Someone would be able to and would like to suggest what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and what you want the overall query to do would all help.

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html, near the bottom of the page where it starts, "JOIN has higher precedence than the comma operator."